# Use Forwardly Declared Template Class in Header C++

Tags: c++

I have a sprite class, which has a templatised data member. It holds an object, which has a pointer to this specialised sprite template class.

That object requires a forward declaration of my sprite class, but since sprite is a template class, I need to include the full header. Therefore I get a cyclic dependancy which I am unable to figure out

Sprite.h

```
#include "myclass.h"
 template<typename SpriteType, typename = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<sf::Transformable, SpriteType> && std::is_base_of_v<sf::Drawable, SpriteType>>>
class Sprite {
public:
    SpriteType s;
    myclass<SpriteType>;
    Sprite() {
    }
    auto foo() {
        return s;
    }

private:

};
```

myclass.h

```
#include "Sprite.h"

//a sprite of type T, is going to create a myclass<Sprite<T>>, a pointer of the Sprite<T> is held in myclass.

template<typename T>
class myclass
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Sprite<T>> ptr;
    myclass() {

    }
private:

};
```

How could I solve this cyclic dependency?

So in summary:

-Sprite is a template class.

-Sprite holds an object to another class. This other class holds a pointer to my this templated sprite class.

-This gives me a cyclic dependency, since both classes are now templates, and need to have their implementations written in their header files.

Comment: You could break this easy just by having the type sprit in nyclass also be a template type. There are undoubtedly other ways, just thought I'd throw that out there as a quicky.

Comment: I dont understand. Could you explain please?

Answer (score 1):

Simplified decoupling, based on @Taekahns solution.

```
template<typename T>
class myclass
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<T> ptr;
    myclass() {

    }
private:

};

template<typename SpriteType, typename = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<sf::Transformable, SpriteType> && std::is_base_of_v<sf::Drawable, SpriteType>>>
class Sprite {
public:
    SpriteType s;
    // DO NOT PASS SpriteType here, put the whole Sprite<SpriteType>
    myclass<Sprite<SpriteType>> t;
    Sprite() {
    }
    auto foo() {
        return s;
    }

private:

};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am so sorry - I am a beginner in C++. I am trying to implement the second suggestion and I am having trouble. Could you help me further please?

Comment: Please describe the problem.

Comment: How is the additional MyClass parameter used in the second example?

Comment: That was a generic decoupling approach. @Taekahn suggested an even better way to go, by cleaning up `my_class` from references to `Sprite`. I would suggest to use his solution.

Comment: I am trying to implement @Taekhan's solution but how could I impose the restricitons onto the template of SpriteType that I need (as mentioned in the problem)

Comment: Simplified for you.

Comment: Sorry, i cut that out for readability, i should have left it in.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I really appreciate it. jvd, how would I change this implementation, should I want to make myclass a pure virtual base class in the future?

Comment: This I do not know. Strictly depends on what the purpose of `myclass` is and what you are doing with it. As it is now, you can only reduce the template-iness if you make pure virtual interface for the `Sprite` class, since in `myclass` you are holding a shared pointer to `Sprite`.

Comment: I understand. jvd, do you reccomend any resources on templates? I have a basic knowledge but I have come to the realisation that pretty much all my debug efforts across my projects involve templates - it is a weakness of mine that I need to improve.

Comment: @jasbindra00 `c++ templates: the complete guide`.  When they say complete, they really mean complete. The book covers everything there is to know about templates in detail.

Answer (score 1):

One of the great thing about templates is breaking type dependencies.
You could do something like this. Simplified for readability.

```
template<typename T>
class myclass
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<T> ptr;
    myclass() {

    }
private:

};

template<typename SpriteType, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<base_class, SpriteType>>>
class Sprite {
public:
    SpriteType s;
    myclass<Sprite<SpriteType>> t;
    Sprite() {
    }
    auto foo() {
        return s;
    }

private:

};
```

That is one of many options.
Another option is to use an interface. i.e. a pure virtual base class that isn't a template.

Example:
I think something like this should do it. Starting to get a hard to follow though.

```
class base_sprite
{
    public:
    virtual ~base_sprite(){};

    virtual int foo() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class myclass
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<base_sprite> ptr;

    myclass() : ptr(std::make_shared<T>())
    {

    };
};

template<typename SpriteType>
class Sprite : public base_sprite{
public:
    myclass<Sprite<SpriteType>> l;
    int foo() override {return 0;};
};
```

Comment: I am attempting to implement this but I cannot insert the template restrictions that I require onto SpriteTyp.

Comment: I've fixedup / updated to add in a constraint, sorry about that.

Comment: No worries, thank you. Taekahn, how would I change this implementation such that my class is now a pure virtual base class, and whos deriviations actually change Sprite? Is this even possible?

Comment: Yeah, Sprite probably makes the most amount of sense. I'll type something up.

Comment: I added an example, though now you could just make myclass take in the `shared_ptr<base_sprite>` and not have myclass as a template. Would probably be cleaner.

Comment: That is so awesome. Thank you Taekahn, I really really appreciate this. It's because of people like you that the C++ community is so freaking awesome!!

Comment: Taekahn, do you have any tips that helped you accelerate your development in C++? I have been studying SFML/C++ since Febuary, and am currently making my own Tetris game from which I am learning lots and lots of things.

Comment: @jasbindra00  books I guess. I also like watching videos from conferences. Sean parent. Scott Meyers. Herb Sutter. All good resources.